# Searching for another way of displaying object of object in Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb

I have data that looks like:

```
[
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('589ba2fb2742a35b47dad21c'),
        'name': 'Iphone7',
        'price': 14500,
        'category': 'Phone',
        'vendor': 'Apple',
        'stock': [
            10,
            40,
        ],
        'quantity': 10,
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('589ba2fb2742a35b47dad21d'),
        'name': 'Samaung TV',
        'price': 6500,
        'category': 'TV',
        'vendor': {
            'name': 'Samaung',
            'phone': '01061202200',
        },
        'stock': [
            5,
            70,
            80,
            34,
        ],
        'quantity': 5,
    },
];
```

I could get second "vendor" which contain phone as like:
`db.products.find({"vendor.phone": {"$exists": true}}).pretty()`

I'm searching for any other way to do get only the vendor that contains "phone" value. I'm new to mongo. thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly why are you searching for an alternative? What does this one fails to achieve?

Comment: It is just a way of testing us in the sessions I take. I searched before coming here but I couldn't find anything. @ Filipe Merker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue `$exists` is the best. However if for some case you insist not to do so you could use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to only find documents where `vendor.phone` is of a certain type.

Under the assumption that all phone numbers are type string you could use this query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "vendor.phone": {
    $type: 2
  }
})
```

If `vendor.phone` can be multiple types you'll have to use an `$or` query to cover all those types like so: (in this example types 1 and 2 represent number and string)

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "vendor.phone": {
        $type: 1
      }
    },
    {
      "vendor.phone": {
        $type: 2
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2mzYnaEPz3j)

Comment: Thanks. @Tom Slabbaert